# Network data with Logstash and Packetbeat

Tags: logging, logstash, packetbeat

I have configured packetbeat to send data to logstash and I have setup a conf file in logstash; however, seems nothing is generated, can anyone advise me for how to collect network data with packetbeat and logstash?

```
input{
    beats{
    port => 5044
    }
}
output{
    stdout{codec=>rubydebug}
    elasticsearch{
        hosts => "localhost"
    }
}
```

Great Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the beats input plugin . try this(non win) :

```
./bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-input-beats
```

[check here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/libbeat/1.2/logstash-installation.html#logstash-setup) also you may need to configure the output properly .
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/packetbeat/current/config-packetbeat-logstash.html